# Representing C#3 code as an Abstract Syntax Tree in XML

Tags: .net, xml, c#-3.0, abstract-syntax-tree

I was wondering if there is something similar to [GCC_XML](http://www.gccxml.org/HTML/Index.html) for C#3; basically a way to represent a program's entire syntactic structure in XML.

Once the representation is created, I was hoping to parse it into an XDocument and interpret or query it from there.

Are there tools out there for this?

Comment: Perhaps you can serialize an expression tree, but that won't help you with raw source code. This is the kind of stuff that Micrsoft is thinking about for C# 5+

Comment: Yeah, exactly; i'd basically LOVE to have something that would be the logical limit of an expression tree (an expression tree that represents an entire executable program: statements, expressions, operators, types, methods, properties, attributes etc etc)  I figured that it would be a bit far out there; so I'd be happy to work with XML as an intermediate for the time being.

Answer (score 2):

Our [DMS Software Reengineering Toolkit can do this with C# 2/3/4](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/DMS/DMSToolkit.html). (EDIT 2014: and now C#5, EDIT 2020: now C#7 working on C#8)

DMS has compiler accurate parsers for C# (as well as Java and many other languages).

It automatically builds full Abstract Syntax Trees for whatever it parses.  Each AST node is stamped with file/line/column for the token that represents that start of that node,
and the final column can be computed by a DMS API call.  It attaches comments to tree nodes so they aren't lost.  DMS can also regenerate valid code from the AST, or from a modified AST; this enables it to be used for code modification or generation.

It has a built-in option to generate XML from the ASTs, complete with node type, source position (as above), and any associated literal value.  The command line call is:

```
 run DMSDomainParser ++XML  <path_to_your_file>
```

DMS itself provides a vast amount of infrastructure for manipulating the ASTs it builds:
traversing, pattern matching (against patterns coded essentially in source form), source-to-source transforms.

It has control flow, data flow, points-to analysis, global call graphs for C, COBOL and Java; that's all coming for C#.

DMS was designed to be a *much* better solution than XML for manipulating such code.